# wikijs - Regular users get 'file upload failed'

Tags: wiki

I gave a group of users edit access only to a specific path /home/ai. Users can edit the pages under this path, but when they **upload pictures it failed** and they get the following:

file upload failed
[image]

In 'Setting' -> 'Group' I set in tabs:

- 'Setting': Redirect login to /home/ai
- 'permission': I checked all the checkboxes under the CONTENT column.
  [image]
- 'Page Rules': I add /home/ai and /ai and give all  the permission
  [image]

Are wikijs have a log where I may find a more details error? which privileges I'm missing?